# How to determine if an ASP page/session hosted in VB or VFP is still active

Tags: session, asp-classic, vbscript

I am hosting a web page with the shell.internet ocx.  The hosted URL is an ASPX page, but my page is classic ASP. How can I know if the session to the hosted page is still alive?

If there is a blip in the internet or the App goes down, the session ends. How can I determine this so I can close my hosted web page gracefully?

Comment: Does the classic ASP page communicate in any way with the ASPX page?

Answer (score 0):

**You should never close web pages.** Leave that up to the user. You should be redirecting the user to the login or some other page and providing them with the appropriate information.

At the top of each page you should check for the presence of the session variable and redirect to the login/error page.